# Kendo datepicker shows two months during animation

Tags: kendo-ui

With the Kendo datepicker we are seeing two months stacked on top of each other when we transition months. Has anyone else seen this? It happens in both firefox and chrome.

```
$(".datepicker").kendoDatePicker();

From <input type="text" id="OrderDateFrom" class="datepicker" name="OrderDateFrom" />
```

As soon as the transition is completed it looks normal again.

UPDATE: Kendo UI Web v2013.1.319, Windows 7 OS using latest versions of Firefox, Chrome, IE 9 & 10, JQuery 1.9.1, HTML5, MVC 2.

Comment: Which OS? Which version of Kendo UI?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The table element created dynamically by the kendoDatePicker plugin cannot have any `clear` css rules applied to it. IE: `clear: both;`

Answer (score 1):

if you are using bootstrap means it will affect your kendo datepicker table.Add below css

```
 #datepickerid_dateview table.k-content
        {
            border-collapse: inherit;
        }
```

datepickertid is your datepicker name.