# Kendo UI DatePicker animation causes duplication of calendar

Tags: jquery, kendo-ui, datepicker

I have a Kendo UI DatePicker. In IE only, when I open it and click on the month, the calendar is being duplicated (question is the same as [Kendo datepicker shows two months during animation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15647583/kendo-datepicker-shows-two-months-during-animation) but the answer there does not work for me):

[image: duplicate kendo calendar]

When I remove a box-sizing style from the element using IE's debugger then the calendar works as expected:

[image]

My question is twofold:

1. does anyone know why box-sizing would cause this to happen?
2. how can I set this property to empty (or completely remove it) using jQuery?

I've tried doing this but it doesn't remove it:

```
$('.k-calendar-container').parent('.k-animation-container').css('box-sizing', '');
```

I've also tried changing the property value from content-box to border-box and while the value is changed, it doesn't fix the problem:

```
$('.k-calendar-container').parent('.k-animation-container').css('box-sizing', 'border-box');
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution I found was to go directly through the stylesheet. However, because it's not a good idea to override kendo.common.less (where the class controllwing the animation container is found), what I did instead was to write my own less file that overrides the kendo stylesheet and contains only classes that need tweaking:

```
kendo-override.less:

/* In the original kendo.common.less file, the class includes
   box-sizing: content-box

   This was causing IE kendo UI DatePicker
   to duplicate the calendar when you clicked to change the month.
*/
.k-animation-container,
.k-animation-container *,
.k-animation-container *:after,
{
   -webkit-box-sizing: content-box; // chrome
   -moz-box-sizing: content-box; // firefox
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do it with CSS, just overwrite this CSS class

```
.k-calendar-table {
  width: 100% !important;
  display:table-cell !important;
}
```