# Kendo Datepicker Shows two month while changing the month

Tags: kendo-ui, kendo-grid, kendo-asp.net-mvc

Hi my kendo datepicker shows two month while change the month of a date picker.Please see the screenshot. I found the below solution [Kendo datepicker shows two months during animation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15647583/kendo-datepicker-shows-two-months-during-animation) . but no luck .Can anyone help to this issue ?

[image]

My Code:

```
@(Html.Kendo().DatePicker().Name("datepicker").Max(DateTime.Today).Events(e => { e.Change("SearchonClick"); }).HtmlAttributes(new { style = "width: 100%", @placeholder = "dd/mm/yyyy", onkeydown = "javascript:return false;" }) )
```

Comment: Please add your html and javascript code of the widget initialization. Perhaps you are not initializing it correctly.

Comment: Please see the code:  @(Html.Kendo().DatePicker()
                .Name("datepicker")
                        .Max(DateTime.Today)
                                .Events(e =>
                         {
                             e.Change("SearchonClick");
                         })
                        .HtmlAttributes(new { style = "width: 100%", @placeholder = "dd/mm/yyyy", onkeydown = "javascript:return false;" })
                )

Comment: Its worked on chrome perfect .but other browser not working properly

Answer (score 0):

The observed problem is surely caused by CSS code that enforces one of the following styles to the popup Calendar's `table` elements:

```
/* any other selector that influences Kendo UI Calendar tables */

table {
    width: 100%;
    /* or */
    float: none;
}
```

The Kendo UI Calendar applies and requires the following styles:

```
.k-calendar .k-content {
    width: 100%;
    float: left;
}
```

The 100% width style is then overridden by a calculated inline pixel width style.

So, if any of the two styles are overridden by non-Kendo UI styles, the Calendar navigation will break. Please check and modify your selectors, so that they do not target Kendo UI Calendar tables.

Answer (score 0):

Finally i found answer

bootstrap.css affect the datepicker table. Add the below css is exact solution.

```
 #datepickerid_dateview table.k-content
        {
            border-collapse: inherit;
        }
```